# Initialize an array of char pointers with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, malloc

```
typedef struct {
    char * array[10];
} List;

int main(void) {
    List input;
    input.array = (char **)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    if (input.array == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        input.array[i] = (char *)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
        if (input.array[i] == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

I am attempting to initialize an array of 10 char pointers that each point to a different string of length 10.

I am receiving the following error from gcc:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[10]’ from type ‘char **’
```

My call to malloc must not be correct, but how so?

Comment: Simple, you can't assign to arrays. Drop the `input.array = (char **)malloc(10 * sizeof(char));` line. Also, [don't **ever** cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)!

Comment: Ah, and people, please don't upvote this question, it's a bad dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char *array[10]` declares an array of 10 pointers to `char`.  It is not necessary to `malloc` storage for this array; it is embedded in `struct List`.  Thus, the first call to `malloc` is unnecessary, as is the check immediately afterward.

The call to `malloc` inside the loop, and check after, are correct.

Also, in C, *do not* cast the return value of `malloc`; it can actually hide bugs.

Also also, `sizeof(char)` is 1 *by definition* and therefore you should never write it.

```
struct List
{
    char *array[10];
};

int
main(void)
{
    struct List input;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        input.array[i] = malloc(10);
        if (!input.array[i])
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /* presumably more code here */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Zack, this is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

malloc(10 * sizeof(char*));

you have to allocate 10 **char pointers** (4 byte / 8byte) and not 10 chars (1 byte)

**//Edit: I ignored the struct. first malloc isn't necessary. See the other answer.**

Comment: But if you do, at least get it correct (`10 * sizeof(*pointeer)`) is safer. But that's still wrong, see the other answer.